# SemanticException 10072: database does not exist (Sqoop)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I created a hive internal table using sqoop command.

```
sqoop import -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096 
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
--connect 'jdbc:mysql://{mysql_url}' 
--username 'xxxx' 
--password 'xxxx' 
--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' 
--split-by id 
--target-dir {hdfs_path}
--verbose -m 1 
--hive-drop-import-delims 
--fields-terminated-by '\t' 
--hive-import 
--hive-table '{table_name}' 
--query "select id from temp WHERE \$CONDITIONS LIMIT 10"
```

I created a table into it and it was working find.

```
19/01/06 19:33:44 DEBUG hive.TableDefWriter: Load statement: LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://hadoop/{hdfs_path}' INTO TABLE `tmp.temp`
19/01/06 19:33:44 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive
19/01/06 19:33:44 DEBUG hive.HiveImport: Using in-process Hive instance.
19/01/06 19:33:44 DEBUG util.SubprocessSecurityManager: Installing subprocess security manager

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:${HADOOP_HOME}/hive-1.1.0-cdh5.14.2/lib/hive-common-1.1.0-cdh5.14.2.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
```

It created in hdfs warehouse location.

```
$ hadoop dfs -ls {hdfs_path}
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

19/01/06 19:43:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 2 items
 0 2019-01-06 19:33 {hdfs_path}/_SUCCESS
65 2019-01-06 19:33 {hdfs_path}/part-m-00000.gz
```

BUT it was an error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10072]: Database does not exist: tmp
```

I already hive-site.xml into sqoop conf directory.

```
cp ${HIVE_HOME}/conf/hive-site.xml ${SQOOP_HOME}/conf/hive-site.xml
```

"hive.metastore.uris" was set local and remote thrift.

How do I do? Help me. Thanks

Comment: what is the value of `{table_name}` and I don't find the information about mysql table and database.

Comment: {table_name} is hive table.

Comment: yeah, that I can tell, I am asking what is the exact value, does it contain table name or table with database?

Comment: so you need to specify --hive-database clause  to import data from sqoop to hive.

Answer (score 0):

Please used this sqoop command to import data from sqoop to hive with existing table and change clause according to your requirement.i have just modified some clause and added some clause as per requirement in your command

```
ubuntu@localhost:/usr/local/hive$ sqoop import -Dmapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096  --connect 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/test' --username 'root' -P --input-fields-terminated-by ',' --split-by id  --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/test_hive --hive-drop-import-delims --fields-terminated-by ',' --hive-import --hive-database default --hive-table test_hive --query "select id from test WHERE \$CONDITIONS LIMIT 10"  --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --delete-target-dir
```

**Happy Hadooppppppppp**